# GCP Error Reporting - Notifying Owner's e-mail

Tags: email, google-cloud-platform, error-handling, cloud, admin

I want to have GCP notifying me on errors to do with Functions.

I have the following setup:

- Error Reporting
- Errors appropriately detected
- API for Error Reporting enabled
- IAM as Project Owner
- Notifying channels (email and telephone number)

There are no muted errors.
What could I be missing?

Comment: If you have enabled Cloud Function API on the project then you can create [log-based-metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics) based on the Stackdriver advanced log filter for Cloud Function. Now, from the created log-based-metric you can create an [alerting-policy](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui#create-policy)  along with e-mail [notification-channel](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#creating_channels).

Comment: Glad that it works for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enabled Cloud Function API on the project then you can create [log-based-metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics) based on the Stackdriver advanced log filter for Cloud Function. Now, from the created log-based-metric you can create an [alerting-policy](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui#create-policy) along with e-mail [notification-channel](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#creating_channels).